# How count() function works?

Tags: python, string, count

Given:

```py
st = "banana"
print(st.count("ana"))
# => 1
```

How come the count is 1, it should be 2 right? please explain to me.

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) of `str.count()`:

> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring *sub* ...

In your case, the occurrences of "ana" are overlapping.

Comment: then how to count even it is overlapping?